# Cannot run Spoon automated tests on OSX

Tags: android, spoon

I was running Spoon tests on the Ubuntu device without any problems, but when I am starting it on OSX I am getting the following exception every time:

```
02:47:58 E/Device: Error during Sync: timeout.
2015-10-21 14:47:58 [SDR.run] InstallException on device [006f0ef0525312ff]
com.android.ddmlib.InstallException
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackage(Device.java:850)
    at com.squareup.spoon.SpoonDeviceRunner.run(SpoonDeviceRunner.java:181)
    at com.squareup.spoon.SpoonRunner.runTests(SpoonRunner.java:153)
    at com.squareup.spoon.SpoonRunner.run(SpoonRunner.java:113)
    at com.squareup.spoon.SpoonRunner.main(SpoonRunner.java:530)
Caused by: com.android.ddmlib.TimeoutException
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.read(AdbHelper.java:769)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.read(AdbHelper.java:737)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.readAdbResponse(AdbHelper.java:226)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.setDevice(AdbHelper.java:855)
    at com.android.ddmlib.SyncService.openSync(SyncService.java:168)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.getSyncService(Device.java:481)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.syncPackageToDevice(Device.java:1051)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackage(Device.java:841)
    ... 4 more
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:210)
    at com.squareup.spoon.DeviceResult$Builder.markInstallAsFailed(DeviceResult.java:113)
    at com.squareup.spoon.SpoonDeviceRunner.run(SpoonDeviceRunner.java:194)
    at com.squareup.spoon.SpoonRunner.runTests(SpoonRunner.java:153)
    at com.squareup.spoon.SpoonRunner.run(SpoonRunner.java:113)
    at com.squareup.spoon.SpoonRunner.main(SpoonRunner.java:530)
```

I am using Spoon runner v 1.2.0. I have adb in the env path, and I am able to install the same apk, with `adb install` command. In addition I was trying to change `ADB_INSTALL_TIMEOUT` in the Android Monitor and set env variable to 15 seconds, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I had **a similar problem running Spoon on an old version of ADB**.

Check that your ADB version is **at least 1.0.31 or later**.